# Hive: casting int runs very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I run this query monthly so I wanted to automate it. However I am having trouble understanding why Query 1 runs VERY slower than Query 2. One possible issue that came in my mind was indexing problem in the table itself, I don't happen to see any indexing problem there.

Another thing I thought it was due to casting that could be a varchar. So, I converted it to int, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem either. What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this?

Query 1

```
select 
* 
from 
table1 
where 
date = cast((year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))*100+month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())))-1 as int);
```

Query 2:

```
select 
* 
from 
table1 
where 
date = 201504;
```

Comment: Does that cast actually work on your version of MySQL server? I've always had to use `CAST(... AS SIGNED|UNSIGNED)`.

Comment: Yes, I used Hive. I am pretty sure it works in MS SQL server also.

Comment: the problem is not only `CAST` but all your functions `unix_timestamp`,`from_unixtime`,`month` etc. because mysql need to execute each one (you have like 10) per every record found. so  - yes, that slows down query a lot

Comment: It works right now but will fail in 8 months :-)  In Jan 2016 it will return `201600`

Comment: Okay Thanks everyone! Let me redesign the query and test it from my end.